# optimize complex logic condition

Tags: c, boolean-logic

I suffered complex C style code logic like as

```
if (A || (B && (X || Y)))
  foo();
```

Is any better way to read the boolean table, or redesign to human readable?

Comment: Readable enough to me if it is a defined logical function. And pretty optimal too, unless you hide some weird stuff behind these letters.

Comment: `if (oktoproceed(A, B, X, Y)) foo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> better way

This is mostly a matter of taste.

A different way to look at OR's and AND's is to treat them as if/elseif/elseif or if/if/if constructs.

So this

```
if (A || (B && (X || Y)))
```

would become

```
if A
  foo();
else if B {
  if X
    foo();
  else if Y
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using boolean variables like:

```
bool one = X || Y;
bool two = one && B;
if(A || two)
```

And also if you want print the results everytime.

Comment: Note that this code is not equivalent to the original one as it is forcing evaluation of both sides of `||` operator, which will not happen in the original code in case `A` is `true` (defeating the short-circuit evaluation).